# Can Azure websites capture custom request headers via a configuration change?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, request-headers

I'd like to capture custom request headers in my Azure websites but I don't have access to the website's source code (ASP.NET).  I do of course have access to the web.config.

Can I capture custom request headers via a configuration change?  I see that IIS allows enabling of advanced logging (https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging#server_logging) which can capture custom request headers but I don't see how to do it on Azure websites.

Comment: what do you mean "capture custom request headers"? You should be able to read headers from HttpContext.Request.Headers

Comment: I'm looking for a means of doing this via configuration, not code.  I don't have access to the code.

Comment: if you do not have access to code, i think it is not do-able as for now. since Azure App Service do not expose IIS setting/config to end-user. But this advance logging seems very useful to end-user, please raise your feedback in https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Azure Web Sites has enabled the Advanced Logging (or Enchanced Logging) so this doesn't seem to be possible using the standard Azure logging mechanism.

But to make sure, have you tried enabling the diagnostics for your site? Especially the Web Server Logs should be interesting for you. The following Azure documentation deals with logging on Azure Web Sites.

[Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/)

Comment: I have.  The web server logs are the only place where headers are captured and unfortunately they don't appear to have an option to log custom headers.